# Azure Billing Enterprise API data issue from may 2019

Tags: azure, rest, api, azure-billing-api

I am observing from last 3 month, we are not getting expected response from azure billing enterprise API. API - https://consumption.azure.com/v3/enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingPeriods/{billingPeriod}/usagedetails From May-2019 we are getting empty data array. Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the following API USAGE DETAILS

```
https://consumption.azure.com/v3/enrollments/{EaEnrollmentNumber}/usagedetails/download?startTime={dateFrom:yyyy-MM-dd}&endTime={dateTo:yyyy-MM-dd}
```